# Trigger on custom object tasks

Tags: trigger

I would like for a field "contacted last 90 days" to be checked if an activity has been performed in that time frame and to uncheck if 90 days has lapsed. If a user hits the log a call or send an email under the activity history is it possible to do this with a trigger since it can't be done with a workflow?

Comment: Hi @Michelle, welcome to SFSE! Your question is asking for other people to write code for you, without presenting a real question or issue. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions that are real problems or errors. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: An addendum. The Answer is "yes". If you write that trigger and find problems be sure to post those problems here and we'll pitch in to help

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to learning [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (free managed package written by @AndrewFawcett), you can get the data you need without writing a single trigger or batch. An example of how to do so is included below:

- Parent Object - e.g. `Account`
- Relationship Name - `WhatId`
- Child Object - `Task`
- Field To Aggregate - `ActivityDate` (you could also try `CreatedDate`
- Field To Order By - `ActivityDate` (won't work without this part)
- Aggregate Operation - `Last` (most recent, whereas `First` would be least recent)
- Aggregate Result Field - e.g. `Most_Recent_Task__c`

[image: Parent Object:Account;Relationship Field:WhatId;Child Object:Task;]

If you want to only cound `Task` records that were in the past, you could add Relationship Criteria along the lines of `ActivityDate < TODAY`.

Once you have the above set up, writing a formula to compare `Most_Recent_Task__c` to `TODAY` is a fairly trivial formula.

You can calculate the most recent value for all records in your org by hitting the `Calculate` button on the `Lookup Rollup Summary` detail page.

[image: Calculate Button]

Answer (score 3):

You may not need code at all for this. There is a sort-of hidden field called `LastActivityDate` which displays the latest ActivityDate on Tasks and past Events related to a record.

You should be able to use this in a checkbox formula field to determine whether the last Activity Date was recent: `IF(TODAY - LastActivityDate > 90, FALSE, TRUE)`

Comment: Just fyi, `IF(CONDITION, FALSE, TRUE)` is syntactically equivalent to just `CONDITION`.

Comment: @Adrian: Agreed, there are several ways to write this formula. `(TODAY - LastActivityDate <= 90)` would work, as would `!(TODAY - LastActivityDate > 90)`. Which one is best has a lot to do with readability and personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with a trigger on Task creation. Just look at the "Name" or "Related To" fields (aka WhoId and WhatId). This will allow you to *tick* the field.

In order to *untick* it, you could use scheduled Apex that runs once a day, iterate over all your custom objects, and untick them if you can't find a recent related activity. However, this can potentially be quite CPU intensive. You may need batch Apex to work around limits.

Comment: Don't check the box, update a `Most Recent Task Date`.

Comment: Yepp, and then create a calculated field. Easier, elegant... :)

Comment: You could also use a time-based Workflow Field Update on the Task for 90 days after the ActivityDate. This way the logic can still be in the Task trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the box with a Trigger pretty easily in an After Trigger.  Do you want Tasks and Events (Since both are considered Activities?).  You could put a Trigger for each, check to see if the WhoId is a Lead, if so do a lookup on the Lead, check the box and update.

To do the Uncheck, you may want to add a Date field that kept track of when the last activity actually was along with a batch that ran nightly that looked for the Date field where the value was greater than 90 days, use the Batch to do the uncheck.

Comment: Pretty similar to what I suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that the SFSE community is not here to write code for you, I would offer that I don't think you need code to accomplish what you're looking for.

If you're feeling really creative and absolutely opposed to writing code, you could accomplish this via Process Builder to launch a flow that would update the related contact/lead record. You'd have to create some formula fields on Task to hold the `WhoId` since you aren't allowed to pass polymorphic fields as variables, but you could construct your logic to fire the appropriate flow if Your_Custom_WhoId__c starts with 00Q (Lead) or 003 (Contact).

Your flow would then populate your checkbox field on the related lead/contact, and I would then also datestamp another field to hold the last contacted date. That way, you could use Time-Based Workflow to uncheck it 90 days after the last contacted date.

That said, this is, in my opinion way easier to accomplish by writing code, but if that's not an option, you could try this solution.

[image: Process Builder on Task]

Comment: I don't think PB works on `Task`, unfortunately.

Comment: Specifically updating parents through the `WhatId`.